# How to redirect from POST to GET?

Tags: html

I have an HTML Page A that receives a POST method from a third-party server.

I would like to redirect Page A immediately to Page B using GET Method. (For some other technical reasons the third-party server cannot communicate directly with page B...)

Is there any way to redirect from the POST Method on Page A to GET in Page B ? I don't care about parameters to be redirected.

I tried the following:

- Add "Location" header in the POST response : Doesn't work.
- Add the following JavaScript in Page A : Basically when Page A is loaded, it redirects to Page B. It works but not very elegant.

  ```
  <script>window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";</script>
  ```

Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: `Location` header _does_ work, but you need to include the appropriate HTTP status cod, which usually starts with a 3. I wrote a small guide on which status code to use here: https://evertpot.com/http/which-redirect-status

Comment: @Evert I tried with the HTTP Code 308 but it's redirected as POST method. Not GET Method. Do you have any ideas please ? Thanks

Comment: `303` or `302` is likely more appropriate and *does* usually change to `GET`. If you're submitting a form and want to send the user somewhere else after processing `303` is best.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Evert.

The answer is :

- Add "Location" header in the POST response **with** 301 HTTP code.